# Проверка id в php и mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать проверку `id` пользователя на странице? `id` есть в базе данных,к которой я сделал подключение.

**Обновление**

Мне нужно, чтобы он считывал `id` пользователя при переходе на другую страницу и позволял ему проводить какие-либо манипуляции на странице. Он переходит на другую страницу, а id  пользователя на может посмотреть, чтобы он смог там что-либо сделать.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id =$_GET['id']; 
} else { 
  exit("Вы зашил на страницу без параметра!");
} 
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
  exit("<p>Неверный формат запроса! Проверьте URL</p>");
}
```

у меня выдает,что я зашел на страницу без параметра, то есть я не указал свой `id`, а мне надо,чтобы это автоматически делалось. Простите, я просто только учусь и еще не во всем разбираюсь.

Comment: Что именно вас интересует? Как проверить существует ли данный id в базе? Можно так: `SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id = YOUR_ID` Постарайтесь формулировать ваши вопросы точнее

Comment: Читайте про сессии. Про куки тоже можете почитать.

Comment: @Visman, спасибо за помощь)) через сессии все исправил))

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно идентификатор пользователя не передают через GET-параметр (адресную строку), где он может быть легко подделан. После аутентификации, заводя сессию пользователя в которой хранят всю необходимую для проверки прав доступа информацию. Данные сессии не покидают сервера, а клиент и сервер обмениваются идентификатором сессии, которую клиент, как правило, хранит в cookie.

Для того, чтобы воспользоваться сессией достаточно вызвать в начале скрипта функцию `session_start()`. После чего можно складировать данные в суперглобальный массив `$_SESSION`.

```
<?php
// Инициализируем сессию
session_start();
...
if($id = is_auth(...)) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
}
```

После этого, на любой странице, где вызывается функция `session_start()` можно пользоваться данными из массива `$_SESSION` (как на запись, так и на чтение).

```
<?php
session_start();
...
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  ...
}
```